# Создание переменной с переменной итератором в имени Java

Tags: java, циклы

Допустим нужно создать много переменных, например 100. Каждая должна иметь название `nameI` где `I` номер переменной(`name1`, `name2` ...). Чтобы не создавать 100 строк в коде, можно ли какой-нибудь инструкцией это объявить в цикле? Вариант создания массива или списка не подходит.

Comment: Можно использовать hashmap, а не писать костыль. Поясни, зачем тебе столько переменных?

Comment: На самом деле надо создать только 10 переменных, но чисто теоритически может быть можно реализовать подобную вещь, и это не будет костылем. Или это только через список?

Comment: @Sergu не могли бы изначальную задачу описать? Мне не хватает фантазии придумать, зачем такое могло понадобиться, а интересно уже стало

Comment: Задача была в исходном виде взята мною из головы, просто хочется именовать переменные используя в названии значения других переменных. То есть динамически создавать именовать переменные в удобном каждому формате.

Comment: @Sergu конечный пользователь в итоге работает с полноценной программой, а не переменными, поэтому ему можно написать "создайте переменную с именем: " ...и когда он пишет "myCustomVar" - можно это название внутри ядра спокойно положить в переменную "wtf" и он не узнает..... А уж как ты на уровне ядра будешь делать - другой вопрос. Так что изначально такое, для разработчика - не требуется. Для пользователя - вообще по-барабану

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответ. Я в принципе это понимаю, просто думал что, может быть это было реализовано на уровне языка. Видимо для этого в том числе и созданы массивы и коллекции.